# Same codes on PHP and Ruby give a different result

Tags: php, ruby, security, encoding, hmac

I'm trying to implement a signature calculating using the sample written on PHP. But these codes return a different result.

PHP sample:

```
base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha384', $message, trim($key), true))
```

Ruby code:

```
hmac_hash = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest("SHA384", key, message)
signature = Base64.encode64(hmac_hash)
```

Here is the message variable is JSON.

Comment: As @Gabor Lengyel says, you need to remove the last param in hash_hmac call in PHP. Also you may need to remove the newlines from the end ruby output in order to compare with the one in PHP

Comment: Yes, but I need to Ruby code returning the same result as PHP above.
I mean that I need to modify Ruby code, not PHP.

Comment: Oh, that's simple. Replace `OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest` with `OpenSSL::HMAC.digest`

Comment: Okay, I found this way to return hmac as raw data. But result still not as on PHP ))
Now, I think, the problem is in encodings...trying to solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest` in Ruby outputs a hex string, and that's what you base64 encode. In your PHP code, the `true` parameter to `hash_hmac` makes it output raw binary data. Without that, it would be hex, which I think would result in the same as the Ruby one.

So you either need to remove the `true` param in PHP code, in order to encode the hex representation in PHP, or use `OpenSSL::HMAC.digest` in Ruby, in order to encode the raw binary data in Ruby.

Also you have `trim()` on the key in PHP but no `.strip` in Ruby, but I don't think that's the problem.